# How do I share @functions across View Pages in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a function in my View called DisplayImage() that works great

```
@foreach (var x in Model)
{
    @Html.Raw(@DisplayImage(x.FrontFileName))
}

@functions {
    public static string DisplayImage(string bagname)
    {
            string img = "http://www.airsicknessbags.com/images/" + bagname + ".jpg";
            string result = "<a href=" + img + " target=\"_blank\">";
            result += "<img src=" + img + " style=\"width: 100px\" />";
            result += "</a>";
            return (result);
    }
}
```

Another page also needs DisplayImage.  Instead of duplicating the code in each View, how do I put (and call) the code from a single place?

I've seen that you can do this with HTML helpers in the App_Code directory of earlier versions of MVC, but I'm using .net Core 3.1.  I've tried RenderSection in both the _Layout.cshtml and in my View page, but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: you can add a static class to the MVC project by moving ``DisplayImage`` from html to this class. and call it in both pages.

Comment: It worked!  I totally missed that methods declared in a View are no different than those in other modules, so thanks.